# fadeToggle with text() bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying  to make a `fadeToggle` effect on jQuery, 
the toggle effect works fine only in the second click on the `<h1>` tag.
in the first click it showing up and hide right after.

noticed that if I remove the `text("how are you")` method and put the inside the paragraph tag, it works perfectrly.

wondering why it doesn't work the first way.
This is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('h1').click(function(){
                $('p').text("how are you").fadeToggle(500);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello jquery</h1>

<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fadeToggle` works the same way as e.g. `toggle` (applies opposed attribute). And since the default state for the `p` element at the begininng is `display: inline` (is visible), then the next default action will be hiding it. That's why you have to define it initially as hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').click(function() {
    $('.x').text("how are you").fadeToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello jquery</h1>
<p class='x' hidden></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly actually - the paragraph element is shown and by clicking on the heading, the function inserts text in it and then toggles fade. As the element is shown, by default (since there are no rules attached to it that would otherwise hide it), the fadeToggle will transition from shown to hidden state.

As stated in the comment above, to make fadeToggle begin by fading an element in, you should first hide the element (either via CSS or via JS, depending on your needs).

Comment: Your JS dynamically inserts text in the paragraph element before initialising the fadeToggle. So paragraph is visible, but has no text, no background and (as it has no content) no height. That's why it looks invisible to the naked eye even though it's visible. If you add height eg. 100px and background eg. red via CSS, you will be able to see the element. 

So you've got a seemingly "invisible" paragraph (to the naked eye) which becomes visible (to the naked eye) after inserting content in it (with it, giving it height as well). However, it's always visible as far as browser is concerned.

Comment: As the fadeToggle determines visibility (as in whether the browser deems the element is visible), it sees that the element is visible and thus, on first click, fades it out. The only reason why you see text suddenly appearing before fading out is exactly because you are inserting it via JS.